# Nginx serves files for the routes that don't exist in the Angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, docker, nginx

I have an Angularjs app (v1) that is built as a Docker image (with Nginx as webserver). The app was built successfully.

I want the app will serve `index.html` when users visit to `http://localhost:5000/content` and `login.html` when going to `http://localhost:5000/content/login`.

Both of paths `/content` and `/content/login` don't exist in that app.

**1. The Dockerfile**

```
# STAGE 1: Compile and Build angular codebase

# Use official node image as the base image
FROM node:10.23.3-alpine as client-app

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy and install all the dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g bower && npm install -g gulp-cli && npm install

# Add the source code to app
COPY . .

# Generate the build of the application
RUN bower install --allow-root

RUN gulp build --max_old_space_size=4096

# STAGE 2: Serve app with nginx server

# Use official nginx image as the base image
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

# Copy the build output to replace the default nginx contents
COPY --from=client-app /usr/src/app /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80
```

**2. nginx/default.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location /content/login {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /login.html;
  }

  location /content {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

}
```

**3. docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  angularjs-app:
    container_name: angularjs-app-docker
    build: .
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
```

This is my app structure after built

```
-app
 --build
   |-app.min.js
   |-app.min.css
   |-login.min.js
   |-login.min.css
 --assets
   |-images
   |-fonts
 --index.html
 --login.html
```

But I went to `http://localhost:5000/content` the app showed "***404 Not Found (nginx/1.21.4)***" message and when visiting `http://localhost:5000/content/login` then all JS and CSS files contain `index.html` content.

Do you have any ideas/solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting index.html back is because Nginx can't find the file you request, and index.html is specified as the fallback in the line

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

For Nginx to be able to find something like `http://localhost:5000/content/site.css`, there needs to be a file called `/usr/share/nginx/html/content/site.css`.

You can change the fallback to a 404 error code if the file doesn't exist if you change the line to

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```